# Internal server error after download on s3 bucket from aws lambda , PHP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bref

I created aws lambda function based on laravel framework using bref. Link: https://bref.sh

this is my code to download using media library spartie

```
$mediaItem = Media::where('model_id',$id)->where('model_type','App\MODEL')->first();

return $mediaItem;
```

My configuration is

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX+XXXXXXXX
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=my-bucket
```

When I download file locally all work perfectly, but when I try to download on s3 in lambda function I got error:

```
{ "message" : "Internal server error" }
```

I use this package  aws:

```
league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0
```

my serverless.yaml

```
service: serverless-api

provider:
    name: aws
    region: eu-central-1
    runtime: provided
    environment:
        APP_ENV: production
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: 
          - s3:*
        Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*'       

plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - public/storage
    - storage/**
    - tests/**
    - .env
 functions:
    website:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:209497400698:layer:php-72-fpm:23
        events:
            -   http: 'ANY /'
            -   http: 'ANY /{proxy+}'
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:209497400698:layer:php-72:22
            - arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:209497400698:layer:console:22
```

also i assign role for s3 , But I have no idea how it's the problem .

thank you .

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Cause I'm having the same problem. All the normal solutions don't seem to work. I ended up just creating a donwload link, which was exactly what I was trying to prevent.
My server setup is also serverless, but by Vapor.

Comment: hi matt , Finally I've found the solution , I am running the function lambda in a vpc , but the vpc does not have permission to access the s3 service so I followed this guide.
https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/
and I ran into another error , By default API Gateway does not support binary HTTP requests or responses like images, PDF, binary files .
so I my case i changed the serverless.yml like the documentation of bref
    apiGateway:
        binaryMediaTypes:
            - '*/*'
    environment:   BREF_BINARY_RESPONSES: 1 
and now it works perfectly .